# Where does VS2010 get default property values when you drag and drop a control in the WPF designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls, designer

Visual Studio 2010 creates default property values when you drag and drop a control in the WPF designer.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestPanel.UserControl1"
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Height=23 and Width=75 are auto generated by the designer.

Does anyone know where the designer gets these values and is it possible to get them runtime in a custom application?

Answer (score 0):

Both `Height` and `Width` are `Dependency Properties` and when you register dependency properties for your control you can set the default value of the dependency property which the `Visual Studio` or `XAML designer` can make use of.

The default value is set inside the `FrameworkPropertyMatadata` class constructor as below code indicates:

```
//Default value is set to Top
Control.VerticalContentAlignmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("VerticalContentAlignment", typeof(VerticalAlignment), typeof(Control), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(VerticalAlignment.Top), new ValidateValueCallback(FrameworkElement.ValidateVerticalAlignmentValue));

//Default value is set to Left
Control.HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HorizontalContentAlignment", typeof(HorizontalAlignment), typeof(Control), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(HorizontalAlignment.Left), new ValidateValueCallback(FrameworkElement.ValidateHorizontalAlignmentValue));
```